# Count the maximum character length for all the data fields in a simplified csv file and output to txt

Tags: text-processing, csv-simple

Given a simplified CSV (max one line per row) with many data fields (>50), how can I count the maximum character length for each data field and then export all the counts to a txt file?
BTW, I want to ignore the first line of the file which contains the column headings.

For example, given the input

```
These,are,the,column_headings_which_may_be_very_long_but_they_don't_count
abcdefghij,abcdefghijk,abcdefghijkl,abc
aardvark,bat,cat,dog
ant,bee,cow,abcdefghijklm
```

The end result could be something like the following, where the first column indicates the data fields in the original file and the second column indicates the maximum length of the field:

```
1 | 10
2 | 11
3 | 12
4 | 13
```

i.e., the length of the longest value in column 1 is 10 (`abcdefghij`),
the length of the longest value in column 2 is 11 (`abcdefghijk`), etc.

I have researched on the site a little bit and found couple ways that can count maximum length in a fairly straightforward manner when a certain data field is specified. For example, use cut and wc commands to count maximum length of the second field in the file:

```
cut -d, -f2 test.csv | wc -L
```

But how can I take the command and loop it over to all the data fields and then output?

Comment: Can you give some sample input?

Comment: Sure. You can download the sample file via this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3-WolEQUW6yM3NZUGhHaVFmdFk/edit?usp=sharing the sample file has 10 columns. thanks

Comment: I had a problem with your link. Can you please just post a small example in your question?

Comment: sorry guys, just fixed the link. please try again. thx!

Comment: guys, since HalosGhost edited the question with a perfect input example, I am going to take the link down. thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this will do what you want:

```
awk -F, 'NR!=1 { if (max_NF < NF) max_NF = NF;
                 for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (max[i] < length($i)) max[i] = length($i) }
         END   { for (i=1; i<=max_NF; i++) printf "%-2d | %d\n", i, max[i] }'
```

Comment: this works! G-man, you are the man. thx

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: (1) “Note that you've got no guarantee of order with `for (i in max)` …” Good point. (2) “That would also cover for columns with only empty fields.” Huh? My current solution handles columns with only empty fields.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I applied your suggestion, however there is nothing returned. Here is the code, am I making any mistake? awk -F, 'NR!=1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (max[i] < length($i)) max[i] = length($i) }
         END   { for (i=1; i<=max_NF; i++) printf "%-2d| %d\n", i, max[i] }' 2014-07-08.csv

Comment: @QYLuo: You need to add code to ***set*** `max_NF`; see my edit.

Comment: regarding empty columns, yes, sorry, I had overlooked the fact that accessing max[i] instantiates the array element. Note that `length(max)` will give you max_NF in GNU awk (but GNU awk only).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your link for the sample file but you can do this by using awk command.
if can specify what ever delimiter you may have and exactly what field you need to count.

```
    awk '{ FS = "," } ; { if(NR!=1) gsub(/"/, "", $2) ; print NR "|" length($2) } ' test.csv
```

You can redirect this output to any file you want.