# how to print a new line in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to print collected data from a file where each set gets a new line (\n)

Code:

```
awk '/mail:|fullName:|uid:/{s=s", "$0} END{print substr(s,3)}' dump2.txt
```

Output now:

```
mail: bogus@bogus.com , fullName: Bogus Bogus, uid: 666  mail: bogus2@bogus.com , fullName: Bogus2 Bogus2, uid: 667
```

Desired output:

```
mail: bogus@bogus.com , fullName: Bogus Bogus, uid: 666 \n
mail: bogus2@bogus.com , fullName: Bogus2 Bogus2, uid: 667 \n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 awk '/mail:|fullName:/{s=s", "$0} /uid:/ {s=s", "$0 "\n" ;} END{printf substr(s,3)}' dump2.txt
```

assuming no % in field

other solution

```
 awk '/mail:|fullName:/{s=s", "$0} /uid:/ {print substr(s,3) ", "$0 ;s=""} ' dump2.txt
```

assuming uid: is last.

Comment: That did give me a new line. But it throws the alignment off. Do you know how to correct it?  http://paste.ee/p/TQQiq  NOTE: there are more than 3 fields. There are about 4 more I need to add.

Comment: I just ensured the last item was in the correct place. All good now!

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add `\n` in desire place :

```
awk '/mail:|fullName:|uid:/{s=s", "$0}\n END{print substr(s,3)}' dump2.txt
```

Comment: awk '/mail:|fullName:|uid:/{s=s", "$0} END{print substr(s,3)}END{print '\n'}' dump2.txt   fails.  awk '/mail:|fullName:|uid:/{s=s", \n"$0} END{print substr(s,3)}' dump2.txt fails.   awk '/mail:|fullName:|uid:/{s=s", "$0} END{print substr(s,3)'\n'}' dump2.txt   fails.   Where to I put it where it will work?  I tried \n\n and \n\n\r  as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another technique: don't store it all up in one big string, print it out as you go along:

```
awk '$1=="mail:" || $1=="fullName:" {printf "%s, ", $0} $1=="uid:"' dump2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: all of the below (obviously) assume that the `uid:` line
will always be the last one of each group. 
However, they all work with `%` characters in the data.

If you want to save up all the data and print it at the end,
here’s a somewhat simple approach, using arrays:

```
awk 'BEGIN {count=0}
     /mail:|fullName:|uid:/ {s[count] = s[count] ", " $0} /uid:/ {count++}
     END {for (i=0; i<count; i++) print substr(s[i],3)}' dump2.txt
```

If you want to be able to handle the fields individually (at the end),
use a two-dimensional array:

```
awk 'BEGIN {count=0}
     /mail:|fullName:|uid:/ {s[count][$1] = $0} /uid:/ {count++}
     END {for (i=0; i<count; i++) printf "%s, %s, %s\n",
                s[i]["mail:"], s[i]["fullName:"], s[i]["uid:"]}' dump2.txt
```

(Like glenn’s answer, this assumes that the `mail:`, `fullName:`, and `uid:` strings appear as the first field in the line.)

I don’t know what you meant when you mentioned alignment,
but, from here, it’s easy to line up the fields in your output:

```
awk 'BEGIN {count=0}
     /mail:|fullName:|uid:/ {s[count][$1] = $0} /uid:/ {count++}
     END {for (i=0; i<count; i++) printf "%23s, %23s, %s\n",
                s[i]["mail:"], s[i]["fullName:"], s[i]["uid:"]}' dump2.txt
```

➘

  ```
    mail: bogus@bogus.com,   fullName: Bogus Bogus, uid: 666
   mail: bogus2@bogus.com, fullName: Bogus2 Bogus2, uid: 667
  ```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {count=0}
     /mail:|fullName:|uid:/ {s[count][$1] = $0} /uid:/ {count++}
     END {for (i=0; i<count; i++) printf "%-23s, %-23s, %s\n",
                s[i]["mail:"], s[i]["fullName:"], s[i]["uid:"]}' dump2.txt
```

➘

  ```
  mail: bogus@bogus.com  , fullName: Bogus Bogus  , uid: 666
  mail: bogus2@bogus.com , fullName: Bogus2 Bogus2, uid: 667
  ```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {count=0}
     /mail:|fullName:|uid:/ {s[count][$1] = $0} /uid:/ {count++}
     END {for (i=0; i<count; i++) printf "%-23s %-24s %s\n",
                                    s[i]["mail:"] ",",
                                    s[i]["fullName:"] ",",
                                    s[i]["uid:"]}' dump2.txt
```

➘

  ```
  mail: bogus@bogus.com,  fullName: Bogus Bogus,   uid: 666
  mail: bogus2@bogus.com, fullName: Bogus2 Bogus2, uid: 667
  ```

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155740/80216)
shows how you can determine the maximum data length for each field.